# Nested Menu list and submenu items are not read as menu and menu item by screen reader

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, voiceover, jaws-screen-reader

I have a menu container, which has list of elements say menu1, menu2 etc. Now each menu item has a submenu list (menu1 has submenu1, submenu2 etc). The code snippet with role attributes is given below:

```
<div role="application">
  <div role="menu" class="loContainer">
    <a href="" class="loTitle">Menu1</a>
    <div role="menuitem">
        <a href="" ng-click="setTopicIdx($index)">Submenu1</a>
    </div>
    <div role="menuitem">
        <a href="" ng-click="setTopicIdx($index)">Submenu2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This read by JAWS 16 in IE11 as "menu Menu1 link, menu submenu1 link, menu submenu2 link"

And in VoiceOver (iPAD AIR iOS11) is read by "Menu1 menuItem menuItem", which is exactly opposite of JAWS behavior. What will the exact roles so that it reads "menu Menu1, menuitem submenu1, menuitem submenu2"?

Answer (score 2):

**All** children of a `role="menu"` should have a `role="menuitem"`.  Your first menu item ("Menu1") is just a link.  Try wrapping it in a `<div role="menuitem">` like your submenus.

```
<div role="menuitem">
  <a href="" class="loTitle">Menu1</a>
</div>
```

Also, for testing purposes (and perhaps your code snippet was just for posting this question), avoid using the word "menu" in your sample text.  If you're listening for the word "menu" because you're testing the `role="menu"` and `role="menuitem"`, and your text contains "menu", it'll be confusing where the word "menu" is coming from.  Is it the role that caused it or the actual text?  In my sample, I used:

```
<div role="application">
  <div role="menu" class="loContainer">
    <div role="menuitem">
      <a href="" class="loTitle">alpha</a>
    </div>
    <div role="menuitem">
      <a href="" ng-click="setTopicIdx($index)">beta</a>
    </div>
    <div role="menuitem">
      <a href="" ng-click="setTopicIdx($index)">gamma</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I noticed you're using `role="application"`.  You'll rarely need to use that role.  Most screen readers will automatically switch between "*browse mode*" and "*forms mode*", depending on the object you tab to.  `role="menu"` is one of those objects that causes the switch.  (You can change your screen reader settings so the switch is not automatic, but I'm trying to keep this simple.)

When the screen reader switches to "*forms mode*" (which is what `role="application"` forces the screen reader to do), then all keystrokes are passed to the application (your javascript code) rather than through the screen reader.  This allows the arrow keys to navigate through your menu rather than through the DOM.  However, using `role="application"` doesn't really do anything for VoiceOver, but it will affect your PC users.  [WebAIM has an article](https://webaim.org/blog/three-things-voiceover/) that explains the modes and how it affects VoiceOver.

In any event, I would recommend removing `role="application"` from your first `<div>` and make sure your menu still works correctly with a PC screen reader such as JAWS or NVDA.

Keep in mind that when you use `role="menu"`, you are committing to managing the keyboard focus yourself.  That is, when the user tabs to the menu and the screen reader user hears "menu", they will assume they can use the left/right arrow keys to navigate through the menu.  If you are **not** allowing the arrow keys to navigate, then you should **not** use `role="menu"`.  See the "[keyboard interaction](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#keyboard-interaction-11)" section for the menu design pattern in the [WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices).

Comment: Thanks for your input. From your code snippet, currently JAWS read **"menu alpha link"**, **"menu beta link"**, **"menu gamma link"**. This is working fine. But what if I want alpha to have submenu links under it as an expandable list, which should read **"submenu alpha 1 link"**, **"submenu alpha 2 link"**, what should be the structure and role in the later case?

Comment: Let me reiterate again that if you're going to use the `menu` and `menuitem` roles, then you're committing to managing the keyboard focus in javascript to allow the arrow keys to navigate through the menu. If that's true, then your submenus should have `aria-haspopup='true'`. However, if you are **not** going to manage the keyboard focus (that is, the user will TAB through the menus instead of using the arrow keys), then you should **not** use `menu` or `menuitem` or `aria-haspopup`. Instead, your submenus should have `aria-expanded`. JAWS won't say "submenu" but will say "expanded/collapsed".